# how to specify the search result using multiple WHERE functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to make some search method for my data table. But I think I don't know some crucial points when using this WHERE function in Ruby.

```
# app/controllers/search_controller.rb 
def posts
category = params[:searched_category]
name = params[:searched_name] 
  animals_categorized = Animal.where(animal_category: category)
  animals_result = animals_categorized.where(animal_name: name)
end

# app/views/search/posts.html.erb
<% @animals_result.each do |animal| %>
  <p><%= animal.weight %></p>
<% end %>

# db/migrate/001_create_animals.rb
t.string :animal_category
t.string :animal_name
t.integer :animal_weight
```

My work is almost like this code. I get multiple parameters(in this case I wrote 2, 'category' and 'name'), then use WHERE function to search results which have the same 'category' and 'name'.

But I have errors like

"SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: animals.animals_name: SELECT  "animals".* FROM "animals"  WHERE "animals"."animal_category" IS NULL AND "animals"."animal_name" = '' LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0".

(I used this 'animal' question because I had too bizarre codes in my original codes that can make me confused what to ask...... sorry)

I think the problem is because of the result which was driven from the first WHERE function. I remember that "WHERE function results in 'array'". So I think 'animals_categorized' is an array that consists of many hash. So second WHERE function cannot work.(my assumption)

What can I do to solve this problem? how can I change the second WHERE function or can you suggest other method that can search results with many parameters given? It will be very thankful if you can just suggest some knowledges because I'm so newbie in programming and I only know Ruby, Ruby on Rails....

Comment: Can you post complete error? Just `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column ` will not help anyone here to understand what's missing. Also, are you sure that `animal_category ` and `animal_name` columns exists in animals table?

Comment: What do you mean by almost like this code?  You can pass multiple parameters to where

Comment: Thank you @User089247 . Those columns exist in the table. When I use one parameter, it works well but two parameters make that errors...

Comment: @JeongbinKim Can you do: `Animal.where(:animal_name => 'some name')`? Does it give the same no such column error?

Comment: @User089247 yes that error pops up.... I don't know what is the problem....

Comment: @User089247, sorry, you got a right point from the first comment...  I made typo in my original code...... I'm too sorry for making you waste your time.... But thanks for you help!! I could finally find my typo because of your comments. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@animals = Animal.all
@animals = @animals.where(animal_category: params[:searched_category]) if params[:searched_category].present?
@animals = @animals.where(animal_name: params[:searched_name]) if params[:searched_name].present?
```

And in view

```
@animals.each do |animal|
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm still getting that error message when I changed my codes according to your answer..... I think I'm missing some other point. What do you think the problem is in my codes above?

Comment: Then the problem is not the where function, but the database itself. Does your `animal` table have both `animal_category` and `animal_name` columns?

Comment: Oh God,,,,, I made terrible mistake in typing my original codes.... I'm really sorry you all.... and Thanks for helping me, I learned how to make 'if conditon tag' behind WHERE function. Thank you very much!!